# How can I fix broken perl permissions?

Tags: perl, permissions, perl-module

I installed a perl module by `force install` and now perl does not work any longer. Somehow this must have set permissions wrong.

```
perl -V
Can't locate Config.pm:   Permission denied.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

How can I fix this? I am on a Mac. I would also do a reinstall or recover stuff from a backup if I only know how or what files.

Comment: This is interesting, I never knew Perl depended on a module to carry out the `-V` option. On my system (Windows 8.1, Cygwin) I found my `Config.pm` module at `/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads/Config.pm`. I tried renaming it to `Config.pm.bak` and running `perl -V`, and got a similar error ("Can't locate Config.pm in @INC..."). Running it without `-V` worked, however. Can you locate your `Config.pm` file on your Mac?

Comment: What module? It might be best to reinstall perl.

Comment: It installed in /Library/Perl/5.18/Flickr/API2/ and did a lot of compilations. The config.pm is in /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm and I can read it. Strange. How do I reinstall the perl that comes with Mac OS? IN earlier times this was on the DVD, but this does not exist any longer ...

Comment: Given that the error message is `Can't locate Config.pm:   Permission denied.` you should check the permissions on `Config.pm` and on the directory that contains it. You should also look at the contents of `@INC`.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Did a clean install from sources. Everything works now. I hope.

Comment: As a "next time" - use perlbrew; it'll install a completely separate Perl instance in your home directory.

Comment: I have this problem again. This time the security on Mac OS is stronger so that I cannot touch /usr/bin/perl. I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Perl: How to fix: "perl -V": Can't locate Config.pm: Permission denied

- Find out what the compiled-in @INC is:

  - sudo perl -V
    @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.18
    /usr/share/perl/5.18
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl"
- For each path **and all of it's parents** make sure that the permissions include "rx", e.g. for "/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2":

  - sudo chmod ugo+rx /usr
  - sudo chmod ugo+rx /usr/local
  - sudo chmod ugo+rx /usr/local/share
  - sudo chmod ugo+rx /usr/local/share/perl
  - sudo chmod ugo+rx /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2

Comment: The suggestion to call sudo perl -V was helpful. I could then see that the path included

/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level

This directory included just one file: perllocal.pod and it was restricted so that only root could enter it.

Once I changed the permissions of the directory so that other users could enter it, everything was fine again.

Comment: I found a permission problem and fixed it. But now it says, "List::Util object version 1.38 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.55 at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 217." So how do I synchronize Perl module versions?

Answer (score 2):

I reinstalled. Yes, I did and now this answer is long enough.

Answer (score -1):

check the $PERL5LIB, echo $PERL5LIB, check if any paths in the $PERL5LIB is permission denied.

eg. in my computer.

`$PERL5LIB
/root/perl5:/home/t7910/usr/perl5:/home/t7910/perl5/lib/perl5`

so, `/root/perl5:` is permission denied.